# flutter GestureDetector for OnLongPressed

Tags: flutter, dart

I know that :

```
onLongPress : The the user touches the screen for longer than 500 milliseconds, onLongPress is fired.
```

what I mean is that if user touches the screen for 2 seconds I fire the Gesture every 500 milliseconds and totally fire that for 4 times .

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your use case?

Answer (score 0):

`onLongPress` should only fire **once**.

If for some reason you are sure it is firing multiple times you could create a boolean value to flip upon firing onLongPress that resets after a specified number of seconds.

Comment: what I am doing is to register a Timer and use Timer.periodic into onLongPress callback. but when I Hand off the button , it is firing and I can't notify when user hand off the button to cancel the timer